# Looping through Google Place API Place Details

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I'm working through the Google Place API documentation and I'm trying to get a script that pulls PlaceIDs from a webpage, and replace them with output from the Google Place API.

I managed to successfully get an output from multiple Place IDs by duplicating the code and changing the variable and function names, but now I'm trying to create a loop function so that I'm not duplicating code. Below is what I have, but I'm getting an error. By looking at the console, it seems to work up till the Callback function where it beaks down.

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at callback (places.html:29)"

I've tried a few things, but no luck so far. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks,

```
<body>
<div id="MY0">ChIJaZ6Hg4iAhYARxTsHnDFJ9zE</div>
<div id="MY1">ChIJT9e323V644kRR6TiEnwcOlA</div>

<script>
    var request = [];
    var service = [];
    var div = [];
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      request[i] = {
      placeId: document.getElementById("MY" + i).innerHTML,
      fields: ['name', 'rating', 'formatted_phone_number', 'geometry', 'reviews', 'photos'],
    };

    service[i] = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.createElement('div'));
    service[i].getDetails(request[i], callback);

    function callback(place, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          div[i] = document.getElementById("MY" + i);
          div[i].innerHTML = "<b>" + place.name + "</b><br>" + place.rating + "<br>" + place.reviews[1].author_name + "<br>" + place.reviews[1].rating + "<br>" + place.reviews[1].text + "<br><img src='" + place.photos[0].getUrl({'maxWidth': 250, 'maxHeight': 250}) + "'>";
      }
    }
    }

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: As a previous poster noted, its the i variable in the callback which is undefined. I'm trying to figure out how to pass the i variable from the loop into the callback.

Comment: Are the callback variables 'place' and 'status' returned from getDetails() ?

Comment: OK -  I see where you got it from - you're using this right? ---> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Why was this (and my answer) downvoted? Seems like a legitimate question

Comment: No idea who downvoted this, but you solved it, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the callback outside of the `for` loop and forget about the array named div (unless you need this...if so I will rewrite). The `for` loop is executing before the getDetails() call returns any result, because this call is asynchronous - since you don't have much control over the Google Places callback, I would save the IDs in an array and then use them in callback, like this:

```
function gp_callback(place, status) {
    var el = document.getElementById(window.id_set[0]); // first in first out - the for loop should populate the IDs in correct order
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        el.innerHTML = "<b>" + place.name + "</b><br>" + place.rating + "<br>" + place.reviews[1].author_name + "<br>" + place.reviews[1].rating + "<br>" + place.reviews[1].text + "<br><img src='" + place.photos[0].getUrl({'maxWidth': 250, 'maxHeight': 250}) + "'>";
    }
    if (window.id_set.length > 1) {
        window.id_set.splice(0, 1); // remove first element from array because has been used - now the next element is at index 0 for the next async callback
    }
}


var request = [];
var service = [];
var id_set = [];
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    request[i] = {
        placeId: document.getElementById("MY" + i).innerHTML,
        fields: ['name', 'rating', 'formatted_phone_number', 'geometry', 'reviews', 'photos'],
    };

    id_set.push("MY" + i); // this ensures array is populated (in proper order, b/c it tracks the execution of the for loop) for use in callback before callback is called (since getDetails() is async)

    service[i] = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.createElement('div'));
    service[i].getDetails(request[i], function(place, status) {
        gp_callback(place, status);
    });
}
```

---

UPDATE: More scalable and elegant answer after I had a little more time to think about it.

```
<div id="MY0" class="gp_container">ChIJaZ6Hg4iAhYARxTsHnDFJ9zE</div>
<div id="MY1" class="gp_container">ChIJT9e323V644kRR6TiEnwcOlA</div>
.
.
.
<div id="MYN" class="gp_container">fvbfsvkjfbvkfvb</div> // the nth div

<script>
    function populate_container(place, status, container_id) {
        var el = document.getElementById(container_id);
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            el.innerHTML = "<b>" + place.name + "</b><br>" + place.rating + "<br>" + place.reviews[1].author_name + "<br>" + place.reviews[1].rating + "<br>" + place.reviews[1].text + "<br><img src='" + place.photos[0].getUrl({'maxWidth': 250, 'maxHeight': 250}) + "'>";
        }
    }

    function call_service(id_request_map) {
        var i, container_id, request,
            service_call = function(container_id, request) {
                var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.createElement('div'));
                service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
                    populate_container(place, status, container_id);
                });
            };
        for(i in id_request_map) {
            service_call(i, id_request_map[i]);
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var request, container_id,
            id_request_map = {},
            container_length = document.getElementsByClassName("gp_container").length,
            i = 0;

        for (; i < container_length; i++) {

            container_id = "MY" + i;

            request = {
                placeId: document.getElementById(container_id).innerHTML,
                fields: ['name', 'rating', 'formatted_phone_number', 'geometry', 'reviews', 'photos'],
            };


            id_request_map[container_id] = request; // build the association map
        }

        call_service(id_request_map);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you, I will need to study this now. Appreciate this.

Comment: I wrote you a more scalable answer when I had some time to think about it a bit...good luck with your project!